# How to handle sorting a set of data that is mapped as components in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have a set of data, JSON array, that I display in my Transfers component using map function, each as a Row component. I want to sort this data using the sort function. I managed to sort the array of data, but the list of (Row)s is not being updated at all. In fact, the constructor for Row for each line is only getting called the first time, before sorting happens.

My aim is not just to sort the data once, so sorting it on componentDidMount is not the solution. I have a button that when clicked, the data is sorted ascending or descending, based on how it was sorted the previous time.

When I print the data before the map statement, it shows that it is sorted correctly.

Edit: The result of the log below is printing the array one time sorted ascending, the next descending.

```
{console.log(this.state.sortedRows)}
{this.state.sortedRows.length>0 ? this.state.sortedRows.map((row,i) => <Row data={row} key={i} id={i} showCommentBox={this.showCommentBox}></Row>) : null}
```

I assume the problem here is that the Row component should not be created every time the render method in Transfer is called. But shouldn't some change happen, since I am using a different set of data to create the Rows?

How can I fix this using this method, or any alternate method to sort the set of Rows?

Comment: you should check `<Row>` shouldComponentUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the array index as a key is problematic when trying to re-order a list’s items or inserting/removing list items. Explicitly passing key={i} silences the warning but has the same problems as array indices and is not recommended in most cases.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#picking-a-key